# Query with '&' character returns NULL, using encodeURIComponent() in JS and urldecode() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my first proper website as a hobby, and i'm having trouble with querying the database when using special characters. **I'm using URI encoding to help with queries containing special characters, like '#', '&', etc.**

Here's basically what's happening:
I list all links from the database:

```php
echo "<li><div class='trapez'><a onclick='getContent(this)';>{$row['title']}</a></div><br><br></li>";
```

Then, `getContent(this)` sends an AJAX request to a PHP file

```js
function getContent(e) {

    var name = encodeURIComponent(e.innerHTML);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "./getSideContent.php?q=" + name , true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

After that, the PHP file decodes the string and queries the database to fetch the content using a prepared statement:

```php
$q = urldecode($_REQUEST["q"]);

$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT heading, content, created_at FROM tab_posts WHERE title= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
$title = $q;
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Now, the content is ready to be displayed by the website, but it seems when using the & character, something in the query goes wrong and the statement returns NULL.

Here's a `var_dump` of the `$_REQUEST['q']` and the result of the query containing '#'

```php
string(12) "Test post #2"

object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["lengths"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(19)
  }
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

And now containing &:

```php
string(15) "Test & post"

object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

By the way there should be an image attached showing that the entry in the database is present.

Even though the variable looks correct, the query returns NULL, and nothing is loaded. What's going on here? What am i doing wrong?
Also, please spare me the 'awful code' comments, this is my first project and i'm just learning.

Comment: It working fine, but you should try use `LIKE`not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always prepare output for the appropriate display environment. For the case of a URL, you've done that correctly. For the case of HTML, use `htmlspecialchars()` on EVERYTHING you output:

```
<?php
$title = htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);
echo <<< HTML
    <li>
        <div class="trapez">
            <a onclick="getContent(this)">$title</a>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
    </li>
HTML;
```

Although a better approach would be to pass the database ID of the row in question:

```
<?php
$id = htmlspecialchars($row["id"]);
$title = htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);
echo <<< HTML
    <li>
        <div class="trapez">
            <a onclick="getContent($id)">$title</a>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
    </li>
HTML;

function getContent(id) {    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "./getSideContent.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(id) , true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

Then your PHP could search more effectively:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT heading, content, created_at FROM tab_posts WHERE id = ?");
```

---

If you're just learning you should welcome criticism of your code. Just from the limited snippets you've shared here:

- rather than returning HTML, you should return JSON data and let your JavaScript callback deal with the presentational aspects of creating HTML elements
- you should have event listeners attached to your elements in a separate JS file, rather than using old-fashioned HTML attributes like `onclick`
- jQuery will save you much work, you should use it
- don't use `$_REQUEST`, it leads to sloppy code, such as...
- your JavaScript is sending the form via POST but you're appending data to the URL
- no need for calling `urldecode()` as your web server already does that
- PDO is much easier to work with than mysqli, and a modern database framework is even easier

Comment: That's a lot of good feedback, i'll definetly take notes. However, the problem still persisted, until i used htmlspecialchars() on the actual input itself, so it's applied to the database entries. Thanks!

Comment: Okay since you've updated the answer, i did in fact do what you posted, and i agree that it is a way better approach. I just didn't think of changing everything. Thanks again!